# Get reference to some class field via reflection in C#

Tags: c#

```
class mapper
{
     List<int> l;
     static Dictionary<string, string> LEGEND = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"list1", "My_FanCyUGLY_N4MEDlst777"}}
     public mapper(MainWindow w)
     {
         l = w.(LEGEND["list1"]);    //how to get this refference?
     }
}
```

In other words, I want to get refference to field (or method, property etc) which name I don't know until runtime. I know I can get the value of that field, but that's not what I want. Is it possible and how to do that?

Comment: Googling "Get reference to some class field via reflection in C#", the first result is the answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, exactly this question, I'm asking right here... Not anything usefull in the first page though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FieldInfo fi = typeof(MainWindow).GetField("fieldname");`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a `FieldInfo` object. Then call [`fi.GetValue(w);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value. The same principle applies for all sorts of members and operations on them.

This is slow at runtime and makes it harder to catch errors at compile time, so make sure you have a very good reason to use reflection here!

Comment: I can remember doing something similar a while ago, but my main problem are fields. Interesting if it's possible to invoke properties/methods to get refference that way, as a workaround

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the question. Updated for fields and added a general statement on this sort of operation.

Comment: Still not that :) Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I'm prety sure this will get those fields's values. I want to get reference to those.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that--as far as I can tell from your example, this would be fine to initialize `l`. Maybe you could make a more specific example that requires a "reference to" the field?

Comment: It is fine to inicialize, but when I change the value of `l` I want the value of `w.My_FanCyUGLY_N4MEDlst777` to also change e.g.

Comment: It actually gets reference to it, my bad

Comment: As far as I know, that is impossible even without reflection. That behavior requires a `ref` parameter in C#, and assigning a field to that parameter will copy the reference value, not make the field act like a `ref` parameter. Maybe if you provide an example without reflection that works the way you want this could be set in stone. **However**: if you mean that you want elements added to `l` to appear in the list acquired through reflection, this will happen. **Edit**: looks like however was the case!